# Testing multistep form with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm not very proficient with Capybara and testing tools alike. I'm building a multistep form or a form wizard.

This is how I had a scenario in my head :

- User visit signup path
- fills in bunch of invalid data and some validation errors should be displayed
- fills in valid data, user should be taken to the next step
- repeat this step above for n steps with valid data
- check if number of users has increased by 1

This is what I've got so far (I managed to get something working) :

```
describe "signup" do
  before { visit signup_path }
  let(:submit) { 'Start creating my account' }
  let(:next_btn) { 'Next' }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end

    describe "should not move to the next step" do
        before { click_button submit }
        it { should have_content('error') }
        it { should have_title('Start here') }
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information wizard step 1" do
    before do
        fill_in 'First name', with: "Example"
        fill_in 'Last name', with: "User"
        fill_in 'email', with: "user@example.com"
        find("#user_password").set "foobar"
    end

    it "should move to the next wizard step 2" do
        click_button submit
        should have_content('We need some more info')
    end
    it "should have error on the wizard step 2" do
        fill_in 'Date of birth', with: "Example"
        click_button next_btn
        should have_content('error')
    end
  end
end
```

This assertion fails `should have error on the wizard step 2`, it seems to be stuck at step 1 still, I know this from looking at page content and by errors where `Dob element can't be found` and `next button` cant be found as well.

Is this even possible with capybara to test sequentially, keeping information step by step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to make this work by nesting the describe blocks when moving on to a subsequent step, eg.

```
describe "signup" do
...

  describe "with valid information wizard step 1" do
    before do
      fill_in 'First name', with: "Example"
      fill_in 'Last name', with: "User"
      fill_in 'email', with: "user@example.com"
      find("#user_password").set "foobar"
      click_button submit
    end
    it "should move to the next wizard step 2" do
      should have_content('We need some more info')
    end

    describe "and filling out the date of birth incorrectly" do
      before do
        fill_in 'Date of birth', with: "Example"
        click_button next_btn
      end

      it "should have error on the wizard step 2" do
        should have_content('error')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now the button clicks are repeated in the nested blocks, so the first example clicks 'submit', and the second example clicks 'submit' and then clicks 'next_btn', etc. Keep in mind that the sequence is repeated for *each example* so this may slow down your tests. OTOH it more accurately reflects the user interaction, so the tradeoff is probably worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a capybara question so much as it is an rspec question.  I've used cucumber more than rspec, but so far as I know in my limited experience, each "describe" is an independent test case.  I don't think that you can either a. expect these to execute in any particular order or b. share context / state between tests.

Again, my experience has mainly been with cucumber, but I have written tests for this EXACT scenario before- a two page user registration wizard.  In cucumber, one writes "scenarios," which are basically short stories that describe a user's interaction with the the system in terms of "given," "when," and "then" (or in other worse, assumptions, actions, and assertions) and these are written in plain English.  One then writes Ruby code that maps these English sentences to Ruby code (which might use capybara) to do / test what each scenario describes... What I did was constructed several distinct scenarios.

1. User visits registration page; fills it out with a whole bunch of errors; check that the system does display the errors
2. User visits registration page; fills it out correctly; check that the user makes it to the second page
3. User has already completed the first page; fills out the second page with a whole bunch of errors; check that the system does display the errors
4. User has already completed the first page; fills out the second page correctly; check that the user makes it to the confirmation page

You can obviously translate those stories into rspec.

The thing that recurs in those scenarios is the filling out (whether with good or bad data) of the two forms.  To keep the code DRY, create some helper methods that let you easily populate the form with values that will help you satisfy each of those scenarios.

Does that help any?

Comment: hi Kent, thanks for your response I've changed the title of the question to be more accurate per your suggestion. While I understand what you're trying to say with regards to keep the code DRY. I'd do that if I'd get tests working first and that is jumping from second step to third step. Right now I'm stuck at the second step as you can see my code and I'm unable to jump to third one. Can you provide a simple code sample assuming each form has only one mandatory field?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know rspec well enough to be much use with a code example.  I was speaking more philosophically in general terms re: to how to approach testing for a wizard.